# Can FormView be used to automatically generate a Create Form (that is strongly-typed)

Tags: c#, webforms, formview, strongly-typed-dataset

I am trying to find an efficient way of designing Create Forms to be able to insert some strongly-typed instances to the database. Normally, I create the tables with the required controls (textbox, label, button, etc.).

I thought FormView could be used to automatically generate the forms when it is strongly-typed (by using ItemType property of the formview). However, I guess it is not possible to do that with FormView. Then, it does not make sense to use FormView for this purpose, is that right?

I also wonder why FormView has DefaultMode that can be set as Insert: DefaultMode="Insert" ?  I checked resources but could not find one an implementation using Insert mode.

Other than scaffolding, is it the best practice that the programmer  create the forms manually?

Answer (score 0):

About creating manually, i think you just need to drop this code in the view:

```html
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
  DataKeyNames="ProductID"     
  RunAt="server">

  <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr><td align="right"><b>Product ID:</b></td>       <td><%# Eval("ProductID") %></td></tr>
      <tr><td align="right"><b>Product Name:</b></td>     <td><%# Eval("ProductName") %></td></tr>
      <tr><td align="right"><b>Category ID:</b></td>      <td><%# Eval("CategoryID") %></td></tr>
      <tr><td align="right"><b>Quantity Per Unit:</b></td><td><%# Eval("QuantityPerUnit") %></td></tr>
      <tr><td align="right"><b>Unit Price:</b></td>       <td><%# Eval("UnitPrice") %></td></tr>
    </table>                 
  </ItemTemplate>                 
</asp:FormView>
```

Comment: I meant to using FormView in Insert Mode to create a new entry.